# how to make pentaho kette trust all self-signed certs?

Tags: ssl, kettle

i'm using kettle RESTClient got following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

i found maybe kettle don't trust self-signed certs by default,but i don't know  how to fix it ,would someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an open issue against the REST step: http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-13846

Feel free to add your vote to the case, maybe it will make it into PDI 6.0 :)